# Get full url of asset, not just the path

Tags: craft3

I'm trying to output the full asset URL. Using Craft 3.0.0-RC7.1

In `.env`:

```
ASSETS_BASE_PATH=/Users/user/code/sitename/web
ASSETS_BASE_URL=http://sitename.test
```

In `config/volumes.php`:

```
'siteAssets' => [
    'path' => getenv('ASSETS_BASE_PATH') . '/assets/images',
    'url' => getenv('ASSETS_BASE_URL') . '/assets/images',
],
```

In my template:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="
{{ entry.socialSharingImage.one.getUrl('socialSharing') }}
" />
```

Output:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="
/index.php?p=actions/assets/generate-transform&amp;transformId=58">
```

As you see, no site url at the start. Any ideas?

It seems the `getUrl()` method returns the path. Prepending it with `{{ siteURL }}` creates two `/`'s e.g. `http://sitename.test//asseturl.jpg`. Same results in dev and production.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can slice the / from the end of {{ siteUrl }} and combine it with getUrl relative path:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="{{ siteUrl|slice(0,-1) }}{{ entry.fieldName.one().getUrl('kafel620') }}">
```

This will produce expected path:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://site.local/assets/images/ramPamPam/headers/_kafel620/tagiatelle.jpg">
```

Answer (score 1):

> Prepending it with `{{ siteURL }}` creates two `/`'s e.g.  `http://sitename.test//asseturl.jpg`

It would do that if you've defined your site URL (either in Settings->Sites->Base URL or using the `CRAFT_SITE` PHP constant) with a trailing slash at the end of it.

i.e. `http://sitename.test/`

Changing it to `http://sitename.test` would work.

Comment: Thanks @Brad Bell - however using the `@web` alias forces a trailing slash upon saving the site settings page. Presumably I would have to set the URL explicitly to avoid this.

Comment: Also, explicitly setting the domain name in Site config also forces a trailing slash on save